# Creating scrollbar with overflow doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, svg

I have written a Whiteboard in Vue. There is simply a svg element and I add other svg-elements like paths to it. I want to scroll in this svg and saw this example, which is quite good.

http://jsfiddle.net/qTFxJ/13/

This is my html part.

```
<svg width="1300px" height="500px" style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;" viewBox="0 0 1300 500" class="flex-item" id="whiteboard" ref="whiteboard"/>
```

And I also have a style part for it.

```
#whiteboard {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I don't know why it's not working. Maybe because of Vue I don't know :(

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have linked, the SVG does not scroll actually. However, the scrollbars you see are part of the `div`.
In order to achieve the same, you have to wrap your max-size SVG into a screen-size div as so:

```
<div style="width: 100px">
   <svg width="1300px" height="500px" style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;" viewBox="0 0 1300 500" class="flex-item" id="whiteboard" ref="whiteboard"></svg>
</div>
```

This will indeed show you scrollbars.